# Finding permutations of a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, permutation

I have a linked list that I'm trying to generate all permutations of.

The link list is made of `ListNode` objects that simply contain an integer and a reference to the next `ListNode`.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public void generatePermutatoins(ListNode head) {
      //code that generates permutations
      //let's say it finds a permutation and stores the entire list in
      //ListNode singlePermutation;
      //printList(singlePermutation);
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a recursive solution as well? I'm quite stuck on any solution, though.

Comment: I did not vote to close but to be honest your question shows that you don't/haven't tried to work on this problem **at all**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it recursively easily if you define your problem correctly.
You have a linked list and a reference to the `head` of the list. You have a function that recursively creates all the permutations of all elements *after* head.
When you get the result you go over each permutation and you add `head` in *each* position generating the last permutation.
If you haven't figured it out this was your recursive function. The following is a skeleton/pseudo code in Java to get you started. The `addEachPosition(permutation, node.value);` adds the value in **all possible** positions in the list

```
public List<List<Integer>> getPermutations(ListNode currentNode) {  
       if(currentNode == null) {  
             return new ArrayList<ListNode>();  
       }   
       List<List<Integer>> nextPermutations = getPermutations(currentNode.next);  
       addToPermutations(currentNode, nextPermutations);  
       return nextPermutations;  
}  

public void addToPermutations(ListNode node, List<List<Integer>> permutations) {  
   for(List<Integer> permutation:permutations) {  
      addEachPosition(permutation, node.value);        
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This non-recursive (iterative) implementation might be helpful: [Collections2.permutations](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/14.0.1/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.java#Collections2.PermutationIterator).